# How to get the id of the URI, to insert it to database after submit? Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a problem where I need to submit or redirect to the page of the same uri.

The main issue here is the url of the id was not read or was not get,
How can I get it to insert to my data.

After I submit the page there is an error

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ArgumentCountError
```

for example my URL is: `http://localhost/project/groups/view_activity/1`

then I need to submit it to the controller `/posts/create_activity`

Here is the Controller `/posts/create_activity`

```
public function create_activity($id){

    $this->post_model->create_activity();

    redirect('groups/view_activity/'.$id);
}
```

And my Model, which I expect that the **$id** is the URI

```
public function create_activity($id){
        // Insert questions

        $field_question = array(
            'question'=>$this->input->post('question'),
            'group_id' => $id
        );

        $this->db->insert('questions', $field_question);
}
```

Form submission

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>posts/create_activity">


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1"><h5> Question: </h5></label>
             <textarea class="form-control" name="question" id="question" rows="8" placeholder="Enter your Question"></textarea>
    </div>

        <hr>


    <input type="submit" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-block btn-info" value="Submit" />

 </form>
```

Comment: Please add your `form` from where you are submitting data.

Comment: @AtalPrateek - i've added it, please see the updated question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `$id` from your `view_activity` controller method to your view or you can directly get it from `uri` in your view.
After that change your`form` `action` to

`<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('posts/create_activity/'.$id); ?>">`.

Alternatively if you do not want it in your `uri` you can add one hidden `input` with the value of `$id`.

Comment: how can I get the id from my view_activity? because `view_activity` is a different controller page, and it has different model..

Comment: here it what my `view_activity controller is  `public function view_activity($id)
 { 
  $data['activities'] = $this->group_model->view_activity($id);
  
  $this->load->view('templates/header');
  $this->load->view('teachers/posts/index', $data);
  $this->load->view('templates/footer');  
    
 }`

Comment: but how can I modify the controller and model? please provide some modification of my code sir, I am really kinda confused :(*

Comment: To pass `$id` from `view_activity` add `$data['id']=$id;` before you load the view.

Comment: ok im done with adding the `$data['id']=$id;` on my `view_activity` ,Now  how can I modify the controller of my `create_activity` and model? how can I receive the id?

Comment: Just add `$id` in your model method.

Comment: $this->post_model->create_activity($id);

Answer (score 0):

Pass the Id into model function

```
$this->post_model->create_activity($id);
```